# mongoDB count deeply nested elements on more then one condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Please, help , I need to find count() of all _a[]._p[] elements having at least one of:

_a[]._p[].s.d.t[].dateP=2022 and _a[]._p[].s.d.t[].tF="N"

and

_a[]._p[].s.c.t[].dateP=2022 and _a[]._p[].s.c.t[].tF="N"

in following type of document:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5c05984246a0201286d4b57a"),
f: "x",
"_a": [
  {
    "_p": [
      {
        "pid": 2,
        "s": {
          "d": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 1,
                "dateP": "20200-09-20",
                
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                "dateP": "2022-09-20",
                "tF": "N"
              }
            ]
          },
          "c": {
            "t": [
              {
                id: 3,
                "dateP": "20300-09-22"
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                "dateP": "2022-09-23",
                "tF": "N"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

In my attempt I can count only the documents that partially match the condition , but not sure if this is correct when there is more nested arrays and not sure how to do it faster and count the _p elements inside the _a:

```
db.collection.count({ "_a._p.s.c.t":{ $elemMatch:{ tF:"N" , dateP: /^2022/i  }  } })
```

The expected result from playground need to look as follow:

```
 { total: 1 }
```

Since the _a._p having s.d.t with id:2 and s.c.t with id:4 match the above condition

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nsCBZs8KcFk)

Comment: do you trying to filter the doc inside `d` and `c`, right?

Comment: this maybe exactly my question how to do the filtering in 3x nested array  considering also the t[] array is under different object d and c  ...

Comment: wll, you need to deconstruct each array first usng `$unwind`

Comment: can this be done without $unwind , collection is pretty huge and 2x $unwind seems affecting performance ..?

Comment: not sure, let me try

Comment: _"... having at least one of ... and ... and ... and ..."_  Would you be more explicit where the _"and's"_ and _"or's"_ go?

Comment: you, cant. you should use it. i dont think if its really affecting performance because a covered query should improve the performance preventing the document scans. Means that is not required to access the disk. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query

Comment: @rickhg12hs : they are only "and"-s , not "or"-s

Comment: @R2D2 Got it.  And you need the count for a specific document, or for all documents in the collection?

Comment: For all documents matching the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it without `"$unwind"`, although the `"$reduce"` nesting levels seem very error prone.  I hope you test this with lots of data before depending on it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_a._p.s.d.t": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "dateP": {"$regex": "^2022"},
          "tF": "N"
        }
      },
      "_a._p.s.c.t": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "dateP": {"$regex": "^2022"},
          "tF": "N"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "ap": "$_a._p"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "docCount": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$ap",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$sum": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$$this",
                  "initialValue": 0,
                  "in": {
                    "$sum": [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "$cond": [
                          {
                            "$and": [
                              {
                                "$reduce": {
                                  "input": "$$this.s.c.t",
                                  "initialValue": false,
                                  "in": {
                                    "$or": [
                                      "$$value",
                                      {
                                        "$and": [
                                          {"$eq": ["$$this.tF", "N"]},
                                          {
                                            "$regexMatch": {
                                              "input": "$$this.dateP",
                                              "regex": "^2022"
                                            }
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "$reduce": {
                                  "input": "$$this.s.d.t",
                                  "initialValue": false,
                                  "in": {
                                    "$or": [
                                      "$$value",
                                      {
                                        "$and": [
                                          {"$eq": ["$$this.tF", "N"]},
                                          {
                                            "$regexMatch": {
                                              "input": "$$this.dateP",
                                              "regex": "^2022"
                                            }
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          1,
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "totalCount": {"$sum": "$docCount"}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L760LSbMdZU).

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

and the solution should be like:

*update: only count element*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      sct: {
        "$size": "$_a._p.s.c.t"
      },
      scd: {
        "$size": "$_a._p.s.d.t"
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[MONGO_PALYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P8wVsZlIfPD)

Comment: As we discussed I search solution without $unwind or the $unwind stage to not be in the beginning of aggregation since it is too expensive  ...

Comment: @R2D2 well, do you need to do filter inside the array or just wanna count all the element? if not, you can remove the `$unwind` and it will still works.

Comment: Just count the elements is best

Comment: i updated my answer, hope it that you expected.

Comment: It is requiered to count the _p elements matching the condition , not count all elements for c.t and d.t

Comment: did you meant like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/6cYgAZbYoIv

Comment: it is not what is  expected , but encouraging you to continue with  +1 for perseverance ... ;)